# Bootstrap 5 responsive Navbar fixed-bottom on Mobile and fixed-left on Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've used Bootstrap 5 Grid system to make a responsive design where the **navbar** moves from left to bottom when size gets lower than `md` (< 768px).

https://jsfiddle.net/ft0d49qm/20/

```html
    <style>
        .fixed {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 751px) {
            .fixed {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                z-index: 10;
            }
        }
    </style>

<body class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100 w-100 p-0">
        <div class="row min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-md-row m-0">
            <!-- Nav -->
            <nav class="col-12 col-md-auto p-md-2 bg-dark">...
            </nav>
            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="col-md-9 p-0 mx-md-auto" style="max-width: 1200px;">...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

#### Mobile Layout: < `md` (<768px)

The wrapper containing `Nav` and `Content` is a `row` and in this layout it is a `d-flex flex-column-reverse`.
This way I've put `Nav` after `Content` and arranged them in a column layout.
`Nav` is `col-12` so that it takes the whole width of the row.
`Content` is by default `col` so that it can wrap to the next line.

Here `Nav` is after `Content` and you need to scroll down to get to it. I would like the `Nav` element to remain fixed to bottom whenever I scroll up or down.
Adding the `fixed` class to it make it stick to the bottom, but the `Nav` size changes randomly on smaller width. Removing the `fixed` class makes the size of the `Nav` remain the same from 0px to 768px.

#### Desktop Layout: > `md` (>768px)

The wrapper containing `Nav` and `Content` is still a `row` but in this layout its a `d-flex flex-md-row`.
This way is the default way.
`Content` is `col-md-9` so that it can be a proper size for the content within.
`Nav` is `col-md-auto` so that it can be as wide as it's widest child-element.

Here `Nav` is just as tall as `Content` and I don't like this. I would like the `Nav` to be something like `height: 100vh;` and remain like that. I need only the `Content` div to be scrollable.
Adding the `fixed` class to it destroys the whole layout.

**I know that this question has been asked a tons of times and I've tried some things (see `fixed` class from the above fiddle) but I couldn't find a solution. The answers from previous questions are either using Bootstrap 4 or simply do not work.**

Also, playing with media queries I noticed that `md` is not actually 768px. When the viewport's width is <= 750px the navbar goes to the bottom and when it's >=751px the navbar goes to the left; so it's more like 751px.
That's why I've used `@media only screen and (max-width: 751px)` for the `.fixed` class.

On the fiddle the breakpoint for `md` is around 785px.

What is happening here ? Are the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) wrong ?